# Regex - Identically Named capture groups during an OR

Tags: regex

I have two scenarios and I want to capture both alternatives using a specific named group.

Scenario 1 - The apple falls far from the tree
Scenario 2 - The really mighty splendid big apple falls far from the tree

Is there a way to capture the fruit in both scenarios without using a lot of question marks and have it fall under the same named group?

The following works but only using two different group names:

```
The (?:(?P<Fruit1>apple)|really mighty splendid big (?P<Fruit2>apple)) falls far from the tree\s?
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ouiziy/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the optional phrase outside the capture:

```
The (?:really mighty splendid big )?(?P<Fruit>apple) falls far from the tree\s?
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2HdK9/1).

Comment: I guess I was really wondering how to make multiple words optional without so many question marks! Thank you!

Comment: It's regex. Get used to question marks :)